# threaded batching with mongoid without using skip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, mongoid

I have a large mongo db that i want to grab a batch of records, process them in a thread, grab the next batch, process in a thread, etc.  There is major decay in .skip as explained in this post https://arpitbhayani.me/blogs/mongodb-cursor-skip-is-slow.  The only way I can figure out how to do this is to take the last id of the current batch as follows (this is non-threaded):

```
batch_size = 1000

starting_id = Person.first.id

batch = Person.where(:id.gte => starting_id).limit(batch_size)

while(batch.present?)
    batch.each do |b|
    # process
    starting_id = batch.last.id
    batch = Person.where(:id.gte => starting_id).limit(batch_size)
end
```

The problem is, the finding is the slow part (relative) and what I really want to do is parallelize this line (I will take care of governing too many threads so that's not an issue):

```
batch = Person.where(:id.gte => starting_id).limit(batch_size)
```

I can't figure out non-skip approach to putting this in a thread because I have to wait until the slow line (above) finishes to start the next thread.  Can anyone think of a way to thread this?  This is what I've tried, but it has almost zero performance improvement:

```
batch_size = 1000
starting_id = Person.first.id
thread_count = 10

keep_going = true

while(keep_going)
    batch = Person.where(:id.gte => starting_id).limit(batch_size)
    if batch.present?
        while Thread.list.count > (thread_count - 1)
            sleep(1)
        end
        Thread.new do
            batch.each do |b|
            # process
            starting_id = batch.last.id
        end
    else
        keep_going = false
    end
end
```

This doesn't quite work, but the structure is not the problem, the main question is how can I get the nth batch of records quickly in mongo / mongoid?  If I could get the nth batch (which is what limit and skip gets me) I could easily parallelize.

thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
while batch.any?
  batch = Person.where(:id.gte => starting_id).order(id: :ASC).limit(batch_size)
  Thread.new{ process batch }
  starting_id = batch.last.id
end
```

Alternatively, add a `processing` key and index and update the documents after they are fetched. It would be done in a single query, so should not be too slow. At least it would be constant time. The batch query would be `.where(:id.gte => starting_id, :processing => nil).limit(batch_size)`

> the main question is how can I get the nth batch of records quickly in mongo / mongoid?

I don't think you need the nth batch, or need to parallelize the query. I believe slow part will be processing each batch...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the challenge is, it's the query itself that i want to parallelize because that's the slow part. If i could fetch the nth and n+1th batch in parallel without skip I could do this.